# Копирование из массивов

Tags: java, list, список

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Максим", "Наташа", "Даша", "Юра"));
        ArrayList<String> secondName = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Иванов", "Петрова", "Сидорова", "Юрьев"));
        ArrayList<String> total = new ArrayList<>();

        //ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Максим Иванов", "Наташа Петрова", "Даша Сидорова", "Юра Юрьев"));

        System.out.println(total);

    }
}
```

Как скопировать из двух массивов строки так чтобы получилось как в закомментированном примере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через цикл пройтись по массивам, сложить строки и добавить в третий массив.

Готовый код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Максим", "Наташа", "Даша", "Юра"));
        ArrayList<String> secondName = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Иванов", "Петрова", "Сидорова", "Юрьев"));
        ArrayList<String> total = new ArrayList<>();

        int arrayLen = firstName.size();
        if (arrayLen == secondName.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
                total.add(firstName.get(i) + " " + secondName.get(i));
            }
        }

        //ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Максим Иванов", "Наташа Петрова", "Даша Сидорова", "Юра Юрьев"));

        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо!